# error of this code

Tags: javascript, sql

please help me

```html
<?php 

// connect db 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','22222222','ecommerce') 

// post value 

  $a_name = @$_POST['a_name']; 
  $a_pass = @$_POST['a_pass']; 

if(isset($_post['login'])){ 
if(empty($a_name) OR empty($a_pass)){ 
     
echo '<script> alert("الرجاء وضع جميع البيانات المطلوبة"); </script>';     
} 
else{ 
// get admin name & admin pass 
$get_admin="select * from admin where a_name = '$a_name' AND a_pass = '$a_pass'"; 
$run_admin = mysqli_query($con, $get_admin); 
// admin isset 
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_admin) == ){ 
$row_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($run_admin); 
// admin valie isset 
$aname = $row_admin['a_name']; 
// cookie here 
setcookie("aname",$aname,time() +60*60*24) 
setcookie("adminlogin",1,()+60*60*24); 
echo '<script> alert("مرحبا بك مرة اخرى يا مدير"); </script>';     

header("location: ok.php"); 
} 
else{ 
echo '<script> alert("البيانات المدخلة غير صحيحة"); </script>';     
} 
} 
} 
?>
```

the error appere for me plz help

```html
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$a_name' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\AppServ\www\ecommerce\admin\login.php on line 9
```

please help me for this error Please help me in this error that shows me a lot and I do not know the solution
thank you

Comment: change to a proper title of your post....

Comment: Do you need a semicolon on end of line 5?

Comment: This post is tagged wrong the code above is PHP, yet you have tagged it as javascript, java and SQL. None of the tags reflect the question. Also, basic syntax question are off topic for stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

This line which contain error `$get_admin="select * from admin where a_name = '$a_name' AND a_pass = '$a_pass'";`
**Solution:**
You should replace this line by this
`$get_admin="select * from admin where a_name = '".$a_name."' AND a_pass = '".$a_pass."'";`

**Final code:**

```
<?php 

// connect db 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','22222222','ecommerce') 

// post value 

  $a_name = @$_POST['a_name']; 
  $a_pass = @$_POST['a_pass']; 

if(isset($_post['login'])){ 
if(empty($a_name) OR empty($a_pass)){ 

echo '<script> alert("الرجاء وضع جميع البيانات المطلوبة"); </script>';     
} 
else{ 
// get admin name & admin pass 
$get_admin="select * from admin where a_name = '".$a_name."' AND a_pass = '".$a_pass."'"; 
$run_admin = mysqli_query($con, $get_admin); 
// admin isset 
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_admin) == ){ 
$row_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($run_admin); 
// admin valie isset 
$aname = $row_admin['a_name']; 
// cookie here 
setcookie("aname",$aname,time() +60*60*24) 
setcookie("adminlogin",1,()+60*60*24); 
echo '<script> alert("مرحبا بك مرة اخرى يا مدير"); </script>';     

header("location: ok.php"); 
} 
else{ 
echo '<script> alert("البيانات المدخلة غير صحيحة"); </script>';     
} 
} 
} 
?>
```

Comment: In `PHP` string concatenation is done using `.` not `+`

Comment: Thanks @Titus , Done editing,dealing with many languages at the same time make me confused =)

Comment: The line that actually contains the error is `$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','22222222','ecommerce')`. The parser gives line numbers for a reason.